# Closure in topology space

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

- We have the set $X$. $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$.
- $\tau$- topology in $X$, $\tau =\{\emptyset, \{1,2,3,4\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}, \{2\}\}.$
- $(X,\tau )$ - space.

$A=\{1,2\}$. Find the closure $\bar{A}$ of $A$ in $(X,\tau )$.

I have found  that $\bar{A}=\{1,2,3,4\}.$

Is it correct? It is my own example. I just want to check my understanding  of this concept. I get this answer by looking at the pictire of this topology.

Are there more time efficient methods for doing this? Maybe some theorem or trick or something like this?

Edit:  the definition from my textbook.

[image]

Comment: In this particular example $2$ belongs to all non-empty open sets. It is a [generic point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_point#Definition_and_motivation). Therefore, it doesn't belong to any closed set, except for the whole space.

Comment: I read carefully the definition. There is not nothing about a generic point. But I understand you. So 2 does not belong to $\bar{A}$? And the answer is $\bar{A}=\{1,3,4\}$?

Comment: No, $2$ is in $A$ and therefore it must be in $\overline{A}$. The observation that I made implies that the only closed set that contains $2$ is the whole space. As a consequence the only closed set that contains $A$ is the whole space. Therefore, $\overline{A}=\{1,2,3,4\}$. A point like $2$, which closure is the whole space is called a *generic point*.

Comment: My approach would be to use the equivalent formula that $\bar A$ is equal to the complement of the interior of the complement of $A$, where the interior of a set is the union of all open sets contained in it.  In this case, the only element of $\mathcal{T}$ contained in $\{ 3, 4 \}$ is $\emptyset$...

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks! I don't know how to assign the comment as the answer but either way I get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. One thing to note is that $\overline{A}$ always contains A. It is the smallest closed set containing A. So in that sense, $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ is the smallest closed set in your space containing $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of closure means that the complement of $\overline{A}$ is precisely the union of all open sets that don’t meet $A$:
$$X\setminus\overline{A} = \bigcup\{U : U\in \tau, A\cap U =\varnothing\}$$

Now $A\cap U=\varnothing$ is equivalent to $A\subset X\setminus U$.

Thus, by taking complements, we see that $\overline{A}$ **is the intersection of all closed sets that contain** $A$:
$$\overline{A} = \bigcap\{X\setminus U : U\in\tau, A\subset X\setminus U\}$$
(**This is true in general and is often the most useful characterization of** $\overline{A}$.)

In your case, you can explicitly list the small collection of closed sets $X\setminus U$. Only the closed set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ contains $A$, so this is the only set in the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

The closure is correct, we add $4$ because $4$ an open set that contains $4$ must be $X$ (just check the list) and thus intersects $A$ as $A$ is non-empty.

An open set that contains $3$ also contains ${2,3}$ and thus intersects $A$ too. So besides $A$ itself we get $3,4$ as points of the closure too. So $\overline{A} = \{1,2,3,4\}$ indeed.